# Route traffic from NIC2 to terminate at NIC1

Tags: routing

I have a Windows 2000 server with two NICs already installed with separate IPs:

- `NIC1`: 172.14.3.113; No gateway
- `NIC2`: 10.15.120.22; Gateway: 10.15.120.1

`NIC2` is for WAN connectivity, and `NIC1` is serving local clients.

`NIC1` is already serving local clients. Now for a remote site, I want people to come in and access using `NIC2`.

Can we route all traffic coming in using `NIC2` to `NIC1`, as everything is working with `NIC1` locally.

Can this be done using the windows route command?

Comment: Just to clarify: Your software (whatever it is) is bound ONLY to `NIC1`, and you've got traffic coming in on `NIC2` that needs to be serviced by your app? What kind of traffic is it? HTTP? Or something else?

Comment: it's not HTTP. It uses port 5000 to connect to sybase database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really an easy problem to solve.

If your application runs over HTTP you can use a Reverse Proxy to do what you want. You set up the Reverse Proxy to listen on `10.15.120.22` and forward all traffic to `172.14.3.113`. `172.14.3.113` will then send its traffic back to `10.15.120.22` and `10.15.120.22` (because it's a smart cookie) will send the traffic back to its originator.

The other option is to run NAT on `NIC2` and then do a port forward to `NIC1`

However, we probably need more information about the kind of traffic that you expect to see routed.

Comment: My application doesn't run over HTTP, it uses port 5000 for communication. Secondly I don't have access to the gateway to make the change. I was thinking if this is solely possible with the windows route command or any other utility that can help.. PLease advise.

Comment: @user75464 - See my update, you can probably do this by running a NAT service on `NIC2` and then port-fowarding. But it's not really possible with `route add` because routing relies on the originator having the proper destination IP address in its headers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... COuld you please explain this in more details. I guess I'm missing out some information. How do I set up a Nat service for NIC2 on Windows 2000 server. Are you talking about the RRAS service here.  What about port forwarding, how can this be done..

Please explain further so that I can try this out and publish the results.

Comment: @user75464 - I've not done port forwarding and NAT in Windows 2000 for a very long time, so I probably can't help you from here, but you're correct that you need to set up RRAS on the box and enable NAT from there. You might want to ask a new question for assistance, as its kind of moved out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's theoretically possible. You'll have to enable packet forwarding on the 2000 server (one guide available [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/using-windows-2000-server-as-a-router/482)), and then you'll have to add static routes to the 10.15.120.1 router (and possibly further up) to enable packets coming in to find the 172.14.3.x network.

Dare I ask why you can't just address the requests to 10.15.120.22?

Comment: I'm assuming that the two NICs are on totally disjointed networks - I've seen similar setups before. But then what needs to happen with packet forwarding like that is that the ORIGINAL packet needs to be addressed to `10.15.120.22`, and the route to that address needs to be followed all the way back to the default gateway at the other end, which is unlikely to happen.

Comment: That's another possibility, yes. Either way, I'm baffled as to what the setup is that is requiring this kind of band-aid.

Comment: As NIC1 is connected to database, which listens to one ip. I want the traffic from NIC2 (remote site) to be serviced by the database, which has to be routed to NIC1 ( as it has the connection to database).